# Slice sentences in a text and storing them in variables

Tags: php, arrays

I have some text inside $content var, like this:

```
$content = $page_data->post_content;
```

I need to slice the content somehow and extract the sentences, inserting each one inside it's own var.
Something like this:

```
$sentence1 = 'first sentence of the text';
$sentence2 = 'second sentence of the text';
```

and so on...

How can I do this?

PS
I am thinking of something like this, but I need somekind of loop for each sentence:

```
$match = null;
preg_match('/(.*?[?\.!]{1,3})/', $content, $match);  
$sentence1 = $match[1];   
$sentence2 = $match[2];
```

Ty:)

Comment: Words delimited by either a dot, comma,?, exclamation mark, ; and so on

Comment: Commas doesn't end sentences, 
So you want to split all your text by punctuations?

Comment: You are right, not commas:) lol, silly me

Comment: Well, this info could have been in your question, don't you think? look at the answer you're getting, they would be the more accurate the more infos you provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a sentence is delimited by terminating punctuation, optionally followed by a space, you can do the following to get the sentences in an array.

```
$sentences = preg_split('/[!?\.]\s?/', $content);
```

You may want to trim any additional spaces as well with

```
$sentences = array_map('trim', $sentences);
```

This way, `$sentences[0]` is the first, `$sentences[1]` is the second and so on.  If you need to loop through them you can use `foreach`:

```
foreach($sentences as $sentence) {
  // Do something with $sentence...
}
```

Comment: Hello, really love your solution, can you make it work in this case? "I am sentence nr one.Followed by sentence nr two" - there is no space after the "." Ty:)

Comment: @webmasters Sorted, the space has been made optional.  Note, however, this will also split punctuated abbreviations like `U.S.A` if it ever occurred in the text.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need them in variables? Can't you use a array?

`$sentence = explode(". ", $page_data->post_content);`

**EDIT:**

If you need variables:

```
$allSentence = explode(". ", $page_data->post_content);
foreach($allSentence as $key => $val)
{
    ${"sentence". $key} = $val;
}
```

Comment: I can't fault you for answering the question, but it ought to be emphasised at every opportunity what a blunder it is to use this kind of code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each sentence ends with full stop, you can use `explode`:

```
$content = $page_data->post_content;
$sentences = explode('.', $content);
```

Now your sentences can be accessed like:

```
echo $sentences[0];    // 1st sentence
echo $sentences[1];    // 2nd sentence
echo $sentences[2];    // 3rd sentence
// and so on
```

Note that you can count total sentences using `count` or `sizeof`:

```
echo count($sentences);
```

*It is not a good idea to create a new variable for each sentence, imagine you might have long piece of text which would require to create that number of variables there by increasing memory usage. You can simply use array index `$sentences[0]`, `$sentences[1]` and so on.*

Answer (score 0):

Don't use individually named variables like `$sentence1`, `$sentence2` etc. Use an array.

```
$sentences = explode('.', $page_data->post_content);
```

This gives you an array of the "sentences" in the variable `$page_data->post_content`, where "sentences" really means sequences of characters between full stops. This logic will get tripped up wherever a full stop is used to mean something other than the end of a sentence (e.g. "Mr. Watson").

Edit: Of course, you can use more sophisticated logic to detect sentence boundaries, as you have suggested. You should still ***use an array***, not create an unknown number of variables with numbers on the ends of their names.